# Prana Pratishta in incomplete temple

Tags: rama, temple, ayodhya

With Rama Mandir opening on 22 January, there is controversy around scriptural alignment. All the four Shankaracharyas are not joining the ceremony (for different reasons); recently Puri and Jyotirmath Acharyas have said it's against Dharma Shaastras, Puranas (Skanda Purana was mentioned according to [news media](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/not-anti-modi-but-seer-says-4-shankaracharyas-not-to-attend-ram-mandir-event-101704963505802-amp.html)).

Questions are:what our scriptures say about prana Pratishta in incomplete structure?
Is there something which prohibits it?
Or, is there something which allows by exception (like, garbha griha is ready, then it can go ahead); if so, what are the basic requirements?

Question is *not about* Ayodhya temple readiness; can apply to any temple.

[For avoidance of controversy here, I would like to note that all four Shankaracharyas have welcomed the effort and supported temple construction; question is around timing of opening ceremony.]

Comment: Here is an interesting resource on Prana Pratishtha in Vishnu temples using Vaikhanasa Agamas -
 https://nsktu.ac.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/M30-Pratishtha-and-Jirnoddhara-by-Prof-Rani-Sadasiva-Murty.pdf

Comment: Prana Prathistha is a complicated tantric process that should be taken care of. It is not a path of bhakti where pure devotion would cancel bad circumstances, it endangers the pujari who performs the puja. The controversy should be addressed by someone who has experience or extensive knowledge of it.

Comment: Pancharatra texts like Jayakhya Samhita & Pauskara Samhita equate the temple with the yantra. Similar to how various avarana devatas of the main deity (situated at the centre of the yantra) are invoked in various sites of the yantra (in the petals, anthers, bhupuras & other corners), the same occurs in the temple. The most visible aspect of invoking avarana devatas are the door-keepers of the temple. Although Pancharatra system isn't followed in North India, the rites of temple consecration (as recorded by Nilakantha Bhatta) do have a heavy Pancharatra influence.

Comment: Similar to how an incomplete icon is never venerated, consecration of a religious structure before it's construction has been completed is also unheard off. The entire meaning of Puja is आत्मवत् सेवा' i.e to serve God in the way the devotee attends to their own body. We never see a builder hand over the a 2 storeyed house to the buyer after having completed only the 2nd floor. And yet we are giving God an incomplete temple to dwell.

Comment: Besides, Agni Purana has compared the temple building with a human body, comparing the shikhara with a human head, garbhagriha with the heart & the consecrated icon within the garbhagriha as the soul. So installing the icon in an incomplete temple becomes similar to installing life in a body devoid of vital organs.